# Can a predator prey isocline, with Holling's Type IV functional response, be generated in R?

Tags: r, matlab

Using R, I am trying to graphically analyze a predator-prey interaction, with a Holling's Type IV functional response, using predator prey isoclines.

This is the script I am using:

```
library(deSolve)
library(phaseR)
model.LV <- function(t, y, parameters){
  with(as.list(parameters),{
    N<-y[1] 
    P<-y[2]
    dN <- r*N*(1-N/K)-(1.511*N/((N^2/9.2724)+N+1.483))*P*N
    dP <- -b*P+(1.511*N/((N^2/9.2724)+N+1.483))*a*P*N

    list(c(dN,dP))
  })
}

params.LV<-c(r=0.8,K=10,b=4.2,a=6)

data.LV<-as.data.frame(lsoda(c(N=3,P=3),seq(1,100,by=0.5), model.LV, params.LV))

plot(data.LV$N, data.LV$P, type="l", col="blue", main="Trajectory for Type-IV Functional Response",
     xlab="Prey density N", ylab="Predator density P", xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,5))
nullclines(model.LV, x.lim=c(0,5),y.lim=c(0,5), parameters=params.LV, system="two.dim", colour=c("green","red"), add=TRUE)
```

The isocline should have a parabola with two vertical lines intersecting it, but the graphic is completely wrong. Can this simulation be ran in R? I've seen it done in MATLAB, and was told that R is probably not powerful enough to run this simulation.

Thank you.

Comment: This gives the trajectory, not the location of the isoclines. You get the isoclines by (1) solving for the equilibria of the ODE, (2) plotting the curves defined by those equilibria

Comment: Nonetheless, you get behavior that looks like a predator-prey system (unstable focus).  You're (probably) _simulating_ the dynamics correctly, but the key word in your question is _analyze_. To do that you need to do a little math and then plot, analytical formulae (which you can plot with `curve`), not simulations. For more detail on simulating such systems, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159830/correct-use-of-desolve-in-ecological-modelling-of-a-predator-prey-system?rq=1

Comment: @jaimedash Thank you. I did manage to get the simulation to work, and am following the link you provided. Cheers!